# how ignore part of the target string

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have some targets in a Makefile as below:

```
A-foobar-int:
    mvn test -Dtest.env=(@:X-foobar-%=%)

B-foobar-qa:
    mvn test -Dtest.env=(@:X-foobar-%=%)

C-foobar-int:
    mvn test -Dtest.env=(@:X-foobar-%=%)
```

Currently, the X as in X-foobar-% is something I am trying to figure out. Basically, what I want to achieve is have a general pattern in all the target actions, instead of `A-foobar-%`, `B-foobar-%`, or `C-foobar-%`. So, what should I do?

Comment: Make isn't that good with wildcards. It can be done, but the solution will be pretty ugly. Are you still interested?

Comment: If it is too ugly, I probably would just prefer hard coded value. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this does what you want:

```
%-foobar-int:
    @echo mvn test -Dtest.env=$(@:$*-foobar-%=%)

%-foobar-qa:
    @echo mvn test -Dtest.env=$(@:$*-foobar-%=%)
```

There's only 2 rules because `A-foobar-int` and `C-foobar-int` are both handled by the first rule. The rules use `$*` to get the value of the stem matched by the target patterns. (And I'm using `echo` to check the results because I not set to run the command.)

Comment: Yes, the $* is exactly the pattern I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to drop the first two tokens of **$@** (when `-` is used as a tokenizer).

Here we go:

```
drop-two-tokens-helper = $(subst $(word 1,$3)$2$(word 2,$3)$2,,$1)

drop-two-tokens = $(call drop-two-tokens-helper,$2$2$2$1,$2,$2$2$2$(subst $2, ,$1))

A-foobar-int:
    mvn test -Dtest.env=$(call drop-two-tokens,$@,-)
```

Comment: It is not working on my mac. make version is this: GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.